# How to select one row in styleframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, styleframe

I want to select the first two rows to apply styles, but I cannot select them.

I have tried many methods, but all cannot work.

```
SH1.apply_style_by_indexes(indexes_to_style=SH1[SH1[0]], styler_obj=Styler(bold=True))
SH1.apply_style_by_indexes(indexes_to_style=SH1[SH1.loc[0]], styler_obj=Styler(bold=True))
SH1.style_alternate_rows(SH1[1], styles=Styler(font_color='green'))
```

> File
>   "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2897, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 1
>
> SH1.style_alternate_rows(SH1[1], styles=Styler(font_color='green'))
>   File
>   "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\StyleFrame\style_frame.py",
>   line 109, in **getitem**
>       return Series(self.data_df.**getitem**(item))   File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2980, in **getitem**
>       indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2899, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198929/discussion-on-question-by-trinidad-how-to-select-one-row-in-styleframe).

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the first and second indexes from `sf.index`:

```
sf = StyleFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
yellow = Styler(bg_color='yellow')
blue = Styler(bg_color='blue')

sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf.index[0], yellow)
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf.index[1], blue)
sf.to_excel().save()
```

Will create

[image]

Comment: Why ‘yellow’ is not defined?

Comment: I also want to ask how to specify the style of columns and how to select the columns names.